# Cannot install glib-dev

Tags: 10.10, dependencies, makefile

I tried to build  [dasher](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/dasher/), but I got it needs `glib`. So doing so this came up:

```
Checking for GLIB... configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0>= 2.6) were not met:
No package 'glib-2.0' found
```

So I tried to install [libglib2.0-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libglib2.0-dev)

It gave another error:

```
libglib2.0-dev:
  Depends: libglib2.0-0 (=2.26.0-0ubuntu1) but 2.26.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
  Depends: libglib2.0-bin but it is not going to be installed
```

What shall I do?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are installing the package with `dpkg`, which doesn't install dependencies. You have to use `apt-get` (aptitude could do too) like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

This way all dependencies needed will be automatically installed.

Answer (score 0):

2.26 refers to GNOME 2.26, which is an old version. Do you have Ubuntu 9.10 or a similar old Ubuntu distribution?

If you can upgrade your distribution, you should be able to solve these problems.
If you cannot upgrade, then get an older package of the source code of the program that compiles with `dasher`.

Comment: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 10.10
Release: 10.10
Codename: maverick

Comment: but i have been upgrading from 9,04..so upgrades didnt go well?

Answer (score 0):

2.26 actually refers to the glib version, not the GNOME version and is current for maverick.  I think you might have just hit a time where certain packages are uninstallable if one arch builds before another.  Does this still fail to install?